# Using the string Match with options!

Tags: string-manipulation, filtering

Here is what I want to do:

I have a list of strings for example

```
s={"red carpet","red box","black carpet","black box"}
```

I want to use something like

```
Select[s, StringMatchQ[#, "red"] &] (*to get an output*)
```

> ```
> {"red carpet","red box"}
> ```

thx in advance for your help

Comment: Try this `Select[s, StringMatchQ[#, ___ ~~ "red" ~~ ___] &]`!!

Comment: Have you seen `StringMatchQ` documentation page?

Comment: I got it now,
Thank you guys

Comment: Or this `Select[s, StringPosition[#, "red"] != {} &]`

Comment: This is using the solution I have you in a comment on your [last question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72615/keep-only-csv-files#comment199144_72615).  When you receive a solution, it's a good idea to try to understand how it works.  Start by looking up the functions in the documentation.  Reading up on StringMatchQ would have immediately solved this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were looking for `StringFreeQ` I think:

```
Select[s, ! StringFreeQ[#, "red"] &]
```

Another way, `StringCases` with a regular expression:

```
StringCases[s, RegularExpression[".*red.*"]] // Flatten
```

Comment: Everyone I know has there own StringContains[] method