# Trim a list of elements

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I suppose this is a trivial question to many of you, please bear with me.

1. I have a long list of words, list1. I would like to "remove all words that contain a specific letter, say "o".

   ```
   list1 = {"world country", "capital", "population", "poppel”, "poppy"}
   DeleteCases[list1, "o" ∼∼ __]  (*does not work*)
   ```

I have tried many things and I have looked through many examples to no avail. I have read through *Patterns* but have not found anything that I can use. Several suggestions here refer to the case where the pattern is a word in the list, like so:

```
list1 = {"world country", "capital", "population", "popp", "poppy"}
DeleteCases[list1, "popp"]

(* Out: {"world country", "capital", "population", "poppy"} (*works*) *)
```

But this is not usable, as I need to have a pattern that means "all words that contain the letter "o")

2. What I am really trying to solve is this: get rid of all words in `list1` that contain the letters in `list3`, such as:

   ```
   list1 = {"world country", "capital", "population", "popp", "poppy"}
   list3 = {"o","q"}
   DeleteCases[list1, list3]  (*does not work*)

   (* My desired output would be {"capital"} *)
   ```

Comment: Take a look at `StringFreeQ`.

Comment: `Select[list1, StringContainsQ["o"]]`

Comment: @Kuba, they forgot to include an operator form of `StringFreeQ`!

Comment: This is almost a duplicate [72670](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72670/5478) but it was marked as a duplicate of more  general question.

Comment: @JasonB I agree :) p.s. OP want's to remove them.

Comment: @Kuba, yes of course, I meant to say `Select[list1, Not@*StringContainsQ["o"]]`

Comment: @Jason, `Not @*`... I dunno what to say. Why not `! StringContainsQ["o"]`, if you're going that way? :P

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @J.M., well probably since `Select[list1, ! StringContainsQ["o"]]` didn't return an answer.  Using composition allowed it to keep its operator form

Comment: @Jason Uff, I didn't notice it was in operator form. You're right. (I still haven't gotten used to those things, actually.)

Comment: Thank you very much, awesome people here! The answer solves the problem very well. As @Louis says, I will vote it up. I will also try to learn and implement the suggestion about StringFreeQ which I understand from the comments is very useful too.

Comment: This is on hold because it is a double or trivial. Maybe there is a site for infrequent users and newbies of Mathematica? I cannot see where the double question is, it is certainly quite informative too. I think the answers here are really too good to be deleted. I upvoted the answer by MarcoB but could not do the same for the suggestion by @Kuba. Also, browsing a lot shows that many users have problem with patterns. I struggle a lot with patterns and have questions about that issue, where can one ask such questions? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
list1 = {"world country", "capital", "population", "popp", "poppy"}
list3 = {"o", "q"}
Select[list1, Not@StringContainsQ[#, Alternatives @@ list3] &]  

(* Out: {"capital"} *)
```

---

Just to flesh out this answer a bit, and because timing things is fun, let's explore Martin's excellent suggestion of using `StringFreeQ` rather than `Not@StringContainsQ` in the `Select` expression.

In order to appreciate the difference, however, we need a longer word list: enter the [SOWPODS word list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOWPODS), used by English-language Scrabble players outside of North America:

```
sowpods = 
 Import["http://www.freescrabbledictionary.com/sowpods/download/sowpods.txt", "List"][[3;;]];

Length[sowpods]
(* Out: 267 751 *)
```

and time the difference, considering also that `StringFreeQ` can take a list of arguments, so `Alternatives` can also be removed:

```
rejectlist = {"o", "q", "a", "e"};

Select[sowpods, Not@StringContainsQ[#, Alternatives @@ rejectlist] &]; // RepeatedTiming
Select[sowpods, StringFreeQ[#, Alternatives @@ rejectlist] &]; // RepeatedTiming
Select[sowpods, StringFreeQ[#, rejectlist] &]; // RepeatedTiming

(* Out: 
{1.8, Null}
{0.61, Null}
{0.368, Null}
*)
```

The most direct `StringFreeQ` approach handily wins.

Comment: @MartinBüttner - your golfing instincts can't stand the extra 20 bytes!

Comment: @JasonB Of course not. :P (It also seems more intuitive and potentially more efficient though.)

Comment: @MartinBüttner That's an excellent point. I added timings to my answer.

Comment: @MartinBüttner another good point indeed. I also added the `Alternatives`-free version to the timing: it is quite a bit faster!

Comment: @Marco From 10.4, `StringContainsQ` is in `C` (see its new `PrintDefinitions`) and it has an operator form. Here are the three timings I get (in the same order as yours, and using the operator form for the first input): `{0.475, Null}, {0.668, Null}, {0.428, Null}`.

Comment: @Xavier thank you for the update! I'll try to add the new timings when I get 10.4